# What does $d \tau s(\tau)$ refer to in this equation and how do I integrate it?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, network

Chapter 10 of *Dynamical Processes on a Complex Network* discusses various aspects of rumor spreading (based on the SIR epidemic model). It contains the following equation for the density of those who remain ignorant of a rumor:

$$i(t) = i(0) exp [- \lambda \langle k \rangle \int ^t_0 d \tau s(\tau )]$$

By combining this with several other equations, they end up with

$$\int_0^t dt \frac{dr}{dt} = \alpha \langle k \rangle \int_0^t d \tau s(\tau) + \frac{\alpha}{\lambda} \int_0^t dt \frac{di}{dt}$$

I suspect I'm missing something obvious, but I'm confused about what the $d \tau s(\tau)$ and $\int_0^t dt \frac{dr}{dt}$ terms refers to and how I can integrate them.

Comment: This is just an alternative notation for integral.  In other words, what you normally see as $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is written as $\int_a^b\,\mathrm{d}x\,f(x)$ instead.  The main benefit is with multiple integrals you can read immediately the range for each variables instead of having to peel off each integral one-by-one.

Comment: @user10354138 So, it's just the integral of $s(\tau)$ in terms of $\tau$ and the integral of $\frac{dr}{dt}$ in terms of $t$? That's pretty straightforward then, I just don't recall having seen it written that way before. The book does use slightly odd notation sometimes, though. Also, any chance you can add that as an answer so that I can accept/upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^t\mathrm{d}\tau\,s(\tau)$ is just an alternative notation for $\int_0^t s(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau$.  There are mainly two reasons why you see this notation from applied mathematics:

1. Usually in applied mathematics the integrand is a complicated function, which doesn't fit in a single line (especially nowadays with two-column layout of journals meaning even less space for displayed equations).  So you usually need to split the integral in multiple lines and it looks weird to have $\int$ in one line and $\mathrm{d}x$ a few lines later.
2. With multiple integrals, it is easier to tell the integration range corresponding to which variables, e.g.,
   $$
   \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^\pi\int_0^1 f(r,\theta,\phi)\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\phi\,\mathrm{d}\theta
   $$
   versus
   $$
   \int_0^{\pi/2}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_0^\pi\mathrm{d}\phi\int_0^1\mathrm{d}r\, f(r,\theta,\phi)
   $$

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense.